# Relative Layout: How to center view in the remaining space to the right of an element?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to center my 'SKIP' button in the center of the remaining space to the **right** of the little Android icon. How can I do this in a relative layout?

[image]

Here's my current XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/min_touch_target_size"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
        android:id="@+id/circle_page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="SKIP"
        style="@style/intro_feature_ad_button_style.right_anchor"
        android:id="@+id/skip_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can try, layout_alignparentright = true , and set ems = 5 or and setting gravity as centre.

Comment: `android:gravity="center"` does nothing.

Comment: then you can use linear layout and set weight to both widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the button in a `FrameLayout` that has `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` and `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/circle_page_indicator"`. The Button needs to have `android:layout_gravity="center"`

[image: Screenshot]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/min_touch_target_size"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
    >
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
        android:id="@+id/circle_page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/circle_page_indicator" 
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="skip"
            android:id="@+id/skip_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: A lot of your suggested code is superfluous, but it did lead me to the right answer. All I needed to do was add `android:layout_alignParent_end="true"` to the button did the trick. If you change your answer to this, I will accept it.

Comment: It is not really centered if you use `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"`. The button will get stretched to the full width. By using `@style/intro_feature_ad_button_style.right_anchor` it is just not noticeable. You asked for centering the button. We should keep my answer as it is in case someone else who reads this question wants to center a button.

Comment: ouch. you are right! I was hoping to avoid having to embed another RelativeLayout

Comment: You can use `alignParentEnd` in your project and accept my answer anyway as it probably is the solution someone who is reading this page is searching for.

Comment: Check out my new edited answer - I think it is the best way to go as it has the least amount of overhead. Feel free to replace yours with it, so I can accept your answer.

Comment: Okay, I removed the overhead and switched to `FrameLayout`. Mostly matches your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/min_touch_target_size"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <ImageView

         android:src="@drawable/ic_android"

         android:id="@+id/circle_page_indicator"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" /> 
        <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button 
        android:text="SKIP" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        style="@style/intro_feature_ad_button_style.right_anchor" android:id="@+id/skip_button" />
         </RelativeLayout>
         </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` does nothing

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick. Wrapped the `Button` in a `FrameLayout` that had `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` and `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/circle_page_indicator"`. The `Button` needed to have it's gravity centered.

Full code below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/min_touch_target_size"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
        android:id="@+id/circle_page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/circle_page_indicator"
        >
        <Button
            android:text="skip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/skip_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Should be `layout_alignParentEnd` instead of `layout_alignParent_end`

Comment: There is another `layout_alignParent_end` in your post :)